# Using Actionlistener to create new frame with JRadioButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, actionlistener

Hi I'm having some trouble creating an actionlistener which creates a new frame with JRadioButtons used as selections.

Ultimately it will be a flashcard quiz program I am creating for fun.

Here's what where I am stuck:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


    public class FlashCard extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon myIcon = new ImageIcon("src/Resources/DNA.png");



    public FlashCard(){
    //Consider using CardLayout format for flashcards.

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 5, 5));

    JButton startButton = new JButton("Begin");

    add(startButton);

    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Execute when button is pressed THIS IS THE PART WHERE I AM STUCK
            JFrame frameAction = new JFrame();
            frameAction.setTitle("Questions");
            frameAction.setSize(350, 150);
            frameAction.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frameAction.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frameAction.setVisible(true);

            frameAction.

    //              JRadioButton jrb1 = new JRadioButton("Student", true);
    //              jrb1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    //              jrb1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //              jrb1.setMnemonic('S');
    //          
    //              ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    //              add(jrb1);
        }
    });

}
```

and here is my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    //Create a frame and set its properties.
    JFrame frame = new FlashCard();
        frame.setTitle("Genetics FlashCard Quiz");
        frame.setSize(350,150);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Create a second frame for when the user
    // clicks begin.

    JFrame question = new JFrame();





}
```

Comment: please help, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Given that both your `JFrames` are the same size & dimensions, your other idea (in the code) of using `CardLayout` was the correct one. Currently your 2nd frame appears over the first giving you the overhead of managing the latter as it is still accessible. If you use `CardLayout` you will be able to easily navigate between multiple `flashcard` panels while maintaining a single interaction area for the user.

See:

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [CardLayout Example](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/?name=Layouts&page=4)